# ASDF initialize-source-registry bug?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf, allegro-cl

I've been banging my head against ASDF2 and just want a sanity check.  When I eval (asdf:initialize-source-registry) with no arguments or with any argument, I get no value.  When I check *source-registry*, I get an empty hash table.  Is this a bug?

I'm on AllegroCL Enterprise 64-bit on Windows 7.

Comment: What is the problem you're having with ASDF2, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds mostly correct to me. In my SBCL init file, I have:

```
(pushnew #p"/home/paulnath/.asdf/" asdf:*central-registry* :test #'equal)
(push #p"/home/paulnath/.asdf/" asdf:*central-registry*)
```

Check section [7.9 in the ASDF manual](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Controlling-where-ASDF-searches-for-systems).

Checking the source of asdf.lisp, the source path ends with a (values), which of course returns no values. So I expect to not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but yes, that behavior is correct.

If you provide an argument to asdf::initialize-source-registry, then asdf::*source-registry* will (probably, you may have no .asd files...) not be empty. Also note that lisp distributions may put their own stuff into asdf::*source-registry*. For example, SBCL puts its internals into it.

The answer given doesn't really answer the question, as asdf::*central-registry* is a different (and supposedly deprecated even though it takes precedence over asdf::*source-registry*) mechanism.